# repaint method of JComponent does not work

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, 2d-games

I am working on a 2D game and now I have got a problem.
My last goal of the following codes is moving an object in a full screen window.

This is some part of my code:

```
public class mainTest {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    DisplayMode displayMode=new DisplayMode(1024,768,64,75);
    GameScreen gameScreen=new GameScreen(displayMode,"background.jpg");
    Sprite s=new Sprite("some.png");
    gameScreen.addSprite(s);
    gameScreen.start();
}
}
```

I have used two kinds of `start()` method. One causes `NullPointerException` and I have commented it and the other does not work:

```
public class GameScreen extends JComponent{
    private Screen screen;
    private ArrayList<Sprite> sprites=new ArrayList<Sprite>();
    private Image background;

    //...(constructor)

    public void addSprite(Sprite sprite)
    {
        sprites.add(sprite);
    }
//  public void draw()
//  {
//      Graphics g=screen.getWindow().getGraphics();
//      g.drawImage(background,0,0,null);
//      for(Sprite i:sprites)
//      {
//          g.drawImage(i.getImage(),(int)i.getX(),(int)i.getY(),null);
//      }
//      g.dispose();
//  }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(background,0,0,null);
        for(Sprite i:sprites)
        {
            g.drawImage(i.getImage(),(int)i.getX(),(int)i.getY(),null);
        }
        g.dispose();
    }
    public void start()
    {
        //draw();
        repaint();
        long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true)
        {
            long elapsedTime=System.currentTimeMillis()-currentTime;
            for(Sprite i:sprites)
            {
                i.update(elapsedTime);
            }
            currentTime+=elapsedTime;
            //draw();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `Sprite` class's `update()` method:

```
public void update(long elapsedTime)
    {
        x+=vx*elapsedTime;
        y+=vy*elapsedTime;
    }
```

While `vx`,`vy` shows velocity.

As you can see, I firstly used method `getGraphicsI()` to get a Graphics object and called its `drawImage()` method in my `draw()` method, but as I said I got `NullPointerException`.So,

1.What does it mean to `getGraphics()` of a window,and

2.Why I get Exception?

3.Why should I `dispose()` `Graphics` object? Or a better question:Should I `dispose()` it?

Then I used another way:Making my class extend `JComponent`, overriding `paintComponent()` and using `repaint()` in my `start()` method.So,

4.Is it suitable to make this class extend `JComponent`?Does it mean `GameScreen` class is a place to draw things on?

5.Why my code does not work? It enters the infinite loop, and does not exit.
But why I don't see anything on the screen?

**UPDATE:**
for more information, this is my `Screen` class:

```
public class Screen {
    private DisplayMode displayMode;
    private JFrame window;
    private GraphicsDevice device;
    public Screen (DisplayMode dm)
    {
        window=new JFrame();
        device=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        displayMode=dm;
    }
    public void setFullScreen()
    {
        device.setFullScreenWindow(window);
        device.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setBackground(Color.black);
        window.setForeground(Color.white);
    }
    public Window getWindow()
    {
        return device.getFullScreenWindow();
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

Stack trace for `NullPointerException`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>
> GameScreen.draw(GameScreen.java:25)   at
>
> GameScreen.start(GameScreen.java:46)  at
>
> mainTest.main(mainTest.java:11)

where line 25 of `GameScreen` class belongs to `getGraphics()` method.

**NOTE:**

My problem is not caused by infinite loop, because I changed the program so that the loop ended after two seconds; but my problem did not solve and I saw nothing on the screen.

Comment: Could you post the exact stack trace of the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: for your question no. 5 you do not have an exit condition for the `while loop` in your `start` method of `GameScreen` class

Comment: @Blip: yes I haven't any but I should see the program result anyway, regardless to infinite loop...

Comment: *but I should see the program result anyway* what do you mean by that? Does your screen show nothing?

Comment: I don't see where you add the GameScreen to the frame.

Comment: @Blip: Yes, my screen show nothing.

Comment: @camickr: `GameScreen` object has a `Screen` object that this object has a frame. So I shouldn't add `GameScreen` to the frame.

Comment: Well, I still don't understand your design. You create a frame and add a component to the frame. The component does not contain the frame. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html) for a better way to structure your program.